# remove lines having the same value in a given column

Tags: text-processing, uniq

I have the input file (sorted by column 2 with -t,):

```
TOP,25424242,T0137,0.08,0.06,0.02,24
TOP,25424242,T0138,0.07,0.06,0.01,24
TOP,17236110,T0138,9.65,9.37,0.28,89
TOP,23525255,T0137,0.40,0.30,0.11,24
TOP,23525255,T0138,0.08,0.07,0.01,24
TOP,21627012,T0138,0.41,0.33,0.08,24
TOP,75856354,T0137,0.18,0.17,0.01,36
TOP,75856354,T0138,0.18,0.17,0.01,26
TOP,42401990,T0137,0.06,0.05,0.01,24
```

I want to get rid of every two lines which have the same value in column 2, so finally get only lines with unique value in field 2 - from example above it would be:

```
TOP,17236110,T0138,9.65,9.37,0.28,89
TOP,21627012,T0138,0.41,0.33,0.08,24
TOP,42401990,T0137,0.06,0.05,0.01,24
```

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
 $ awk -F, '{a[$2]=$0; b[$2]++;} END{for(i in a){if(b[i]==1){print a[i]}}}' file
TOP,17236110,T0138,9.65,9.37,0.28,89
TOP,21627012,T0138,0.41,0.33,0.08,24
TOP,42401990,T0137,0.06,0.05,0.01,24
```

Comment: thank you, it works on example  but when I process huge file (same sorted by second column, finally when processed your awk code output is unsored in column 2. I can't explain why it is not processed one-by-one, numbers in second column should be incremental in column 2 as it was before processing...

Comment: @DonJ this is why you need to always mention all of your requirements in the original question. You didn't say anything about sorting and awk iterates over arrays in random order. Just pass the output through `| sort -t, -k2`.

Answer (score 2):

Short **`uniq`** trick for your current input structure(with static first 2 fields length):

```
uniq -s4 -w8 -u file
```

- `-s4` - skip the first 4 chars (i.e. `TOP,`)
- `-w8` - compare no more than 8 characters in lines
- `-u` - only print unique lines

---

The output:

```
TOP,17236110,T0138,9.65,9.37,0.28,89
TOP,21627012,T0138,0.41,0.33,0.08,24
TOP,42401990,T0137,0.06,0.05,0.01,24
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using awk:

```sh
for k in `awk -F "," '{print $2}' file.txt | uniq -D`; do
  sed -i '/'$k'/d' file.txt;
done
```

Output

```
TOP,17236110,T0138,9.65,9.37,0.28,89
TOP,21627012,T0138,0.41,0.33,0.08,24
TOP,42401990,T0137,0.06,0.05,0.01,24
```

Comment: Please copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net so it can tell you about some of the issues but also that will fail when key values can be substrings of other key values and/or appear elsewhere in  the input so it's a bad approach plus if you were going to do this it could be done with `grep -f` or other better ways.